# Adding state to the end of another components state, only when a button is pushed

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have three components:

- PageBuilder - is basically a form where the user adds a page name and selects some items.
- PageList - stores all pages the user has created in state and renders that state as a list
- PageUpdater - takes the form info from PageBuilder and adds it to PageList

When someone clicks a button in PageBuilder, PageBuilder pushes its state to PageUpdater:

```
  // PageBuilder

addNewPage = () => {
  let info = {...this.state};
  this.props.callBack(info);
}
render(){
return <button onClick={this.addNewPage}>New Page</button>
}
```

PageUpdater receives state from PageBuilder and passes it down to PageList as props

```
// PageUpdater

constructor(props){
super(props);
this.state={
  data: ''
}
 }
 updatePageList = (pageAdded) =>{
  this.setState({data:pageAdded});
 }

render(){
  return(
  <div>
   <PageBuilder callBack={this.updatePageList}/>
   <PageList addToList={this.state.data} />
  </div>
   )
}}
```

PageList receives the object in props and adds it to its own state. It then returns that state as a list

```
// PageList

constructor(props){
super(props);
this.state = {pages:''};
}

componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
 this.setState({pages: [...this.state.pages, nextProps.addToList]});
}

getPages = () => {
  var pages = []
  for(var key in this.state.pages){
      pages.push(this.state.pages[key].pageTitle)}
  return pages; // Return an array with the names
 }


 render(){
   return(
      <div>
         {this.getPages().map((page, index) => <li key={index}> {page} </li>)}
      </div>
   )
 }}
```

The problem is that I'm using componentWillReceiveProps to tell PageList when to update its state. So every time the props change, PageUpdaters state is added to the PageList. I only want this to happen when the user clicks the new page button (in the PageBuilder).

Answer (score 0):

One of the main principles of React is that every state is managed by *one* component, you change and manage your list through three components. Instead your pagelist should be a stateless component:

```
 const PageList = ({ pages }) => (<div>
   { pages.map(({ pageTitle }, index) => <li key={index} >{pageTitle}</li> ) }
  </div>);
```

Now `Page` should contain the pages in its state and provide a method to change it:

```
 class Page extends React.Component {
   state = { pages: [] };

   addPage = (page) => {
     this.setState(({ pages }) => ({ pages: pages.concat(page) }));
   }

   render() {
     return (<div>
       <PageList pages={this.state.pages} />
       <PageBuilder add={this.addPage} />
     </div>);
   }
}
```

Now the PageBuilder only has to call `this.props.add({ pageTitle: "something" })` ...

Comment: PageList needs to have state as it has to keep track of various other page properties like descriptions, images etc. When the user clicks on a list item, they will be able to view the page and its properties.

Comment: @george nope. `pages` is owned by `Page`, only `Page` should change it.

Comment: PageBuilder allows the user to add a name and select elements that they want on their page. The users choices are saved in state. 

When the user decides to create a new page, their last page is sent to PageList and PageBuilders state is cleared so that the user can make new choices.

PageUpdater is the Parent of these two components. 

The purpose of PageList is to keep track of all the pages the user has created and all of the properties of those pages